# Getting a result from a change in connection settings (wifi or 3G on) and closing the system settings

Tags: android

My activity opens the systems prefs when no internet connection is connected.
What is the best way to close the system prefs and go back to the activity as soon as the user activates wifi or 3g.

Is there a way to get a result using startActivityForRsults()? 
Should I wake up the activity using a listener that detects when a connection is on?

Thank you or your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to close the system prefs and go back to the activity as soon as the user activates wifi or 3g.

The user can press the BACK button to do this.

> Is there a way to get a result using startActivityForRsults()?

AFAIK, none of the Settings activities are designed for `startActivityForResult()`.

> Should I wake up the activity using a listener that detects when a connection is on?

No.

Please do not break Android navigation. What you are proposing is the same as if the user clicked a link on your Web page to visit a different site, clicked on a checkbox on that third-party page, and you now expecting to have some way to force the user immediately back to your page. That's not how the Web works, and what you are proposing is not how Android works. Please allow the **user** to decide what to do next, whether that is press BACK to return to you, press HOME to go do something else, etc.

Comment: With the web example - thats actually **exactly** how Oauth does work. I infact have this very same problem for a app I writing for use in a vertical application where the user will **not** have access to the back button. I know its a very specialised use case, but its androids openess with the Intents system that allows for this kind of customised use and I'd prefer not to re-implement the existing Wifi settings Activity if I can help it.

Comment: @Maks: "With the web example - thats actually exactly how Oauth does work" -- no, it is not. OAuth requires participation on *both sides*, not just one side. "in a vertical application where the user will not have access to the back button" -- unless you are making your own firmware, they most certainly will have access to the BACK button, because you cannot stop it in another app.

Comment: that is quite true from a implementation point of view, but from the **users** point of view, what the user sees is that you click on a button (eg. here on SO to login), you go to a website (eg. google) you authorise SO by ticking a box and then you get automatically redirected back to SO. 

In regards to a vertical app, yes changing the 'firmware' is an option (eg. CM9 allows exactly this) especially on devices with no hardware back button, but I am trying to avoid writing my own Wifi settings activity or forking the AOSP one, which I think the OP is trying to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you need to register a **BroadcastReceiver** for **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** and then check the intent that you receive to make sure that you now how network connectivity and if so then you can use startActivity to go on to what ever of your activites you want to display next.